# Is it possible to get the actual width of an image contained in a div smaller that it?

Tags: jquery, image, width

Let's say I have an image whose actual width is `1000px`, but its width in CSS is set as 100% and it is contained in a `500px` wide `div`.

Is there a way for jQuery to know that the image is actually 1000px wide even though its width on the page is only 500px?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using [`naturalWidth`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#dom-img-naturalwidth):

```
var realWidth = imgElement.naturalWidth;
```

Comment: Wow. How well is that supported, in your experience? (It's not mentioned in [DOM2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-17701901), for instance, but of course that's quite antiquated.)

Comment: I've personally not had problems with it, but it's worth pointing out that I'm purely a hobbyist and do this for fun (I know, I know...), so I'm not as experienced with cross-browser support issues as most others on this site.

Comment: Even so, nice one! (That's my +1, I didn't know about `naturalWidth`.)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a new image with the same `src` off-page, and measure that.

For instance, if your existing `img` element has the `id` `"foo"`, then:

```
$("<img>")
    .css({
         position: "absolute",
         left: -10000,
         top: 0
    })
    .on("load", function() {
        var realWidth = this.width;
        var realHeight = this.height;
        $(this).remove();

        // Use `realWidth` and `realHeight` here
    })
    .appendTo(document.body)
    .attr("src", $("#foo").attr("src"));
```

Comment: But wouldn't that approach be immediately compromised by `img { width: 100%; }`?

Comment: @DavidThomas: If someone has a blanket rule setting the width of **all** `img` elements, it could be compromised, yes. (I don't think your specific example would affect the above, though.)

Comment: Agreed, I guess I was raising a (potential) caveat, rather than advising against the approach; I can't imagine anyone would want to have such a generic rule while also wanting to find out the image's inherent size.